# Use user login as default credential with Apache Zeppelin

Tags: jdbc, shiro, apache-zeppelin

With Apache Zeppelin 0.7.2, I have setup LDAP authentication and would like to "forward" the user login to JDBC (a Spark thrift server) instead of the default "hive".

I see Zeppelin has something called "credentials", but that means all users must fill it with any value :/

I am going to automatically generate this file (`credentials.json`) with all users, or maybe there is a better solution?